# Install Magento 1.9 on localhost FAIL

Tags: magento, localhost, magento-1.9

I tried to install magento 1.9 on my local, it return me errors below

```
Warning: require_once(lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/pin/Sites/magento/downloader/index.php on line 32

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /Users/pin/Sites/magento/downloader/index.php on line 32
```

I tried to add

> ../ infont of lib/Mage

but still getting errors, can someone guide me how to solve this problem, Appreciate that if you could help me solve this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is restrictive filesystem permissions. Please [read the docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html), and set the appropriate file/folder permissions then try again:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```